# Azure Storage Account Networking Tab is not shown/Accessible

Tags: azure, networking, azure-storage-account

I am the only one who is not able to access the Azure Storage Account Networking tab in West Europe or other people are having the same problem?

Comment: I don't see any issue with West Europe Storage Account. 
Could you please share the SS here?

Comment: There was an issue with the Storage account which trigger in Azure Service Health yesterday evening.        "We identified a recent deployment task as the potential root cause and have cancelled the rollout for the deployment. We are currently performing a manual rollback to a previous known working configuration as mitigation.

Comment: Between approximately 11:20 UTC and 17:58 UTC on 27 Sep 2021, you were identified as a customer who may have been unable to see Firewall and Virtual Network blade and Private Endpoint Connection blades under the Networking section of your Storage account in your Azure Portal. Programmatic methods such as PowerShell, Azure CLI, and APIs were not affected. Additionally, certain features may be unavailable when creating new storage accounts. This issue is now mitigated.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the Storage account which trigger in Azure Service Health yesterday evening. [image]

Between approximately 11:20 UTC and 17:58 UTC on 27 Sep 2021, you were identified as a customer who may have been unable to see Firewall and Virtual Network blade and Private Endpoint Connection blades under the Networking section of your Storage account in your Azure Portal. Programmatic methods such as PowerShell, Azure CLI, and APIs were not affected. Additionally, certain features may be unavailable when creating new storage accounts. This issue is now mitigated.